# VB.NET - For each checked item in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, contains, strip

This is probably easy as well. But I have this listview which contains exe files I've listed up. Now, I want to execute these exe files in turn from which items are checked or not.

So, I've tried this:

```
For each item in listView1.CheckedItems
    Msgbox item.ToString
Next
```

Cause I noticed that the item in checkedItems doesn't contain much. And if I convert it to a string, it ends up in the msgbox looking like this: `ListViewItem: {Filename.exe}`

Now, I want the filename obviously. But is there any other way of extracting the name only? Or do I have to strip the string to remove the `ListViewItem: {` part away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first step should have been to consult the [documentation of `ListViewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx) to find out how to retrieve the required information from the object.

The `Text` property is what you’re after.

```
For Each item in listView1.CheckedItems
    MsgBox(item.Text)
Next
```

Comment: I'm sorry, intellisense didn't show the Item property. I thought there were little properties there :) This clears it up pretty nicely then :) You learn something new every day I guess! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
For each item in listView1.CheckedItems
    Msgbox item.Text
Next
```

This should work for winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Msgbox item.Text`?

Answer (score 0):

Your probably lookin for more of something like this. This will have the item and the subitems. You will need a loop with in a loop to accomplish this. Hopes this helps

```
     Dim x As Integer = 0
     Dim y As Integer = 0
     For Each item In listView1.CheckedItems
         For Each subitem In listView1.CheckedItems(y).SubItems
            MsgBox(subitem.Text)
            x = x + 1
         Next
      y = y + 1
    Next
```